# AsyncTaskLoader incorrect method call onLoadFinished

Tags: android

I'm trying to deal with AsyncTaskLoader. I implemented the Interface LoaderCallbacks  follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<String> {
...
...
@Override
public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.w("loader","onCreate");
    return new JSONLoader(this);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.w("loader","finish");

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> arg0) {
    Log.w("loader","onReset");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void useLoader() {

    Log.w("loader","useLoader");
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      // ...
      // fill in args
      // ...


      Loader loader = 
         this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);

      Log.w("HashLoader",String.valueOf(loader.hashCode()));
      // with support library: 
      // Loader loader = 
      //    context2.getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
      // call forceLoad() to start processing
      loader.forceLoad();

   }
```

I get a hung event for button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            useLoader();
        }
    });
```

When I push the button the first time the method onLoadFinished() is called after the loader. But when push button a second time it calls the first onLoadFinished().

Logcat :

```
useLoader
onCreate
1087415440
good
finish
useLoader
finish
1087415440
good
```

A little about AsyncTaskLoader:

```
public class JSONLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {

public JSONLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String loadInBackground() {
            try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.w("loader","good");
        return " ";}
```

Why does the method onLoadFinished() not wait for the end of the Thread?

Answer (score 3):

I think the `initLoader` function doesn't **destroy** and **create** a new loader. then  on the second run, your custom loader has already been 'loaded' => it calls `onLoadFinish()`

try to destroy it and recreate it simply by replacing the `initLoader` call by a `restartLoader`
( [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29) )

```
Loader loader = this.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
```